# LU factorization of a non-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to find $L$ and $U$ for the following non-symmetric matrix $A$:

$
 A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & r & r & r \\
a & b & s & s \\ 
a & b & c & t \\
a & b & c & d\\
     \end{bmatrix}
$

I'm not sure how the matrix being non-symmetric helps me. Does $A$ have to be a square matrix which is symmetric and invertible? Do I need to calculate its determinant to be nonzero in the first place?

Since I don't know the answers to the above questions, I calculated $U$ anyway:

$
 U = \begin{bmatrix}
a&r&r&r\\
0&b-r&s-r&s-r\\ 
0&0&c-s&b-s\\
0&0&0&d-b
     \end{bmatrix}
$

But I don't know how to proceed about $L$.

I'd also know what are the four conditions to get $A=LU$ with four pivots. I think the diagonal elements of both $L$ and $U$ must be nonzero to get four pivot elements, right? So $a \neq 0, b \neq r, c \neq s, d \neq b$, am I right?

Comment: Please explain in a way that will help me solve other exercises on my own, thank you.

Comment: Yes, rank $4$ is exactly equivalent to $a\ne0$, $b\ne r$, $c\ne s$ and $d\ne b$. But the $LU$ decomposition exists anyway (in some cases you have to switch rows, so one speaks about $P^TLU$, where $P$ is a permutation matrix).

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for your response (and for removing *strange* spaces). Could you also provide an answer to my first question about the non-symmetric matrix? When does $LU$ decomposition not exist?

Comment: It mostly depends on what you mean by $LU$ decomposition; if you just want $L$ lower triangular and $U$ upper triangular, then it doesn't exist when the Gaussian elimination *requires* row switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get $A=LU$, you need to set up the elimination matrices, $E_k$.  In other words, the row operations that you do in order to obtain $U$ can be written as matrices.  Thus depending on how many you need, $U$ can be written as
$$E_nE_{n-1}...E_2E_1A=U$$
To get $L$, calculate $(E_nE_{n-1}...E_2E_1)^{-1}$
By the inverse rule, 
$$L=(E_nE_{n-1}...E_2E_1)^{-1}=E_1^{-1}E_2^{-1}...E_{n-1}^{-1}E_n^{-1}$$
In regards to your conditions you are correct.

Comment: Thank you. How exactly should I calculate those inverse matrices?

Comment: Oh I got it, they're the same as elimination matrices except that the corresponding elements are positive.

Comment: I'd be delighted if you could answer my first question: I'm not sure how the matrix being non-symmetric helps me. Does $A$ have to be a square matrix which is symmetric and invertible? Do I need to calculate its determinant to be nonzero in the first place? "

Comment: Upper and lower triangular matrices are by definition square, therefore A itself must be square.  As far as invertibility, I don't believe that is required, because even if one of your pivots is 0, as long as your matrix has all zeros below (or above) the main diagonal, the process of elimination, i.e,. the elimination matrices are themselves all invertible.

Comment: Thank you, that was very informative.

Answer (score 2):

If $b\ne r$, $c\ne s$, you indeed get the $LU$ decomposition
$$
A=LU=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-a & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-a & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-a & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\,
\begin{bmatrix}
a&r&r&r\\
0&b-r&s-r&s-r\\ 
0&0&c-s&b-s\\
0&0&0&d-b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The conditions $a\ne0$ and $d\ne b$ are irrelevant. If $a=0$ and $b=d$ the rank is $2$; if $a=0$ and $d\ne b$ the rank is $3$; if $a\ne0$ and $d=b$ the rank is $3$; if $a\ne0$ and $d\ne b$ the rank is $4$.

However, the $LU$ decomposition doesn't always exist. Let's see the case $b=s=r$, so that the first step in the elimination produces
$$
U = \begin{bmatrix}
a&r&r&r\\
0&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&c-s&0\\
0&0&0&d-b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If $c\ne s$ or $d\ne b$, there's no way to write $A=LU$ with $L$ lower triangular and $U$ upper triangular.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when $a=0$ and $b=d$ we don't have four pivot elements, do we?

Comment: @Gigili No, but this doesn't mean you don't have an $LU$ decomposition.

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks. I'd be delighted if you could answer my first question: "I'm not sure how the matrix being non-symmetric helps me. Does $A$ have to be a square matrix which is symmetric and invertible? Do I need to calculate its determinant to be nonzero in the first place? "